# Typescript property does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm making a simple tree menu element in Aurelia using a jQuery plugin. I am able to use the plugin in the element, but it throws an TS compile error.

> client:47 ./src/tree.ts
>   (18,32): error TS2339: Property 'jstree' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'

Why is throwing this error and how do I eliminate it?

Additional info:

The element renders okay. I started from working from the webpack - typescript starter kit. Relevant code is below. I used `npm install jstree` to include the jstree library.

**tree.ts**:

```
import { inject, customElement } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { DOM } from 'aurelia-pal'
import 'jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css'
import 'jstree'

@customElement('tree')
@inject( DOM.Element )
export class Tree {
  element : HTMLElement = null;

  constructor ( element : HTMLElement ){
     this.element  = element;
  }

  attached() {
    $( '#' + this.element.id ).jstree({
    'core' : {
    'data' : [
      {
          "text" : "Root node",
          "state" : {"opened" : true },
          "children" : [
              {
                "text" : "Child node 1",
                "state" : { "selected" : true },
                "icon" : "fa fa-file-o"
              },
              { "text" : "Child node 2", "state" : { "disabled" : true } }
          ]
    }]
   }});
  }

}
```

**tree.html**:

```
<template></template>
```

other modules (welcome.ts / welcome.html)

```
  <require from="./tree"></require>
  <tree id="menuTree"></tree>
```

Comment: Do you have the jstree.d.ts file installed?

Comment: nope, I will have to read up on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the definitions file for jstree:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jstree/jstree.d.ts

Easiest way to do this would be to use `typings`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings

```
npm install typings --global
typings install jstree
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right solution, i had to ```typings install dt~jquery``` too which resulted in other issues